# How to Change TextBlock Background Dynamically On An Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background, textblock

Currently, I have a binding from a textblock in XAML to a Brush variable in the code. If I set this variable statically, before I run the code, it will change it correctly. However, if I change the variable during runtime, on a click for example, the textblock doesn't update. Is there some function that needs to be used to update the window or something like that?

Comment: What have you done already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you change to color without notifying. The binding cannot know the color changed.

What you need to do is implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the propertyChanged event in the Color property' setter. This way, your binding will work as expected. (look at this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Another way is to implement Color as a dependency property. That way, you won't have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged  interface./

Have a look at this :

Comment: Thanks a ton, this was my problem. I got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Binding by the sound of it, rather than setting the `TextBlock.Background`? property to your variable:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyPropertyName");
myBinding.Source = ViewModel.MyPropertyName;
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBlock, TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, myBinding);
```

You will also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel to fire the PropertyChanged event and notify the UI that the property has changed.

Comment: Well currently I have a binding, from the TextBlock in XAML:   <TextBlock Background="{Binding Color}" /> and in the code-behind, I try to change Color during runtime and it doesn't update. Is this not enough? I know the binding is working, because if I set Color before the program starts, it will start off as that color.

Comment: Is your code behind set as the DataContext of the control and have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: If you are wanting to change the colour from an event handler, you had might as well just set the TextBlock.Background from the event handler rather than trying to bind it as data binding is more suited to MVVM architecture